# Nested jquery ui slider in accordian on slide to change div content

Tags: jquery, events, user-interface

Basically, I want to have the gray box of each slice-accordian div change when the slider is moved with a corresponding .text() that acts like a popover but within the gray box with Min/Max values corresponding to set information that gets updated (i.e. move up and this is where you are at and this is the information for this value of the slider). A bonus is if the handle of the slider can change color to correspond to the value range (i.e. Max=Red, Default=Green, Min=Red).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to recreate your example as closely as possible (read: not changing any other code that could be cleaned up).

I have put together an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/peK2s/1/) doing what I think you need it to do.

Your ranges were off for the thresholds for different colours, with not having min and max ranges they were overwriting each other.

For the updating of text in the grey box, it is a simple case of looking for it in the DOM relative to the slider being interacted with e.g

`$(this).parent().siblings('.feelings-box').html('blah')`

Comment: Thanks so much. Almost there except how can unique values per slider? be called and placed within the <p> tags? Would that be a matter of calling each (creating variables for each step/slider/frame-content) or by creating an array of values and using unique array objects? Also, on what CSS/DOM element should a touch/click event so that the accordion slides open by default and prevents the sliders from being moved without the accordion opening?

Comment: Apologies, had missed this notification. I have updated the example now at: http://jsfiddle.net/peK2s/3/ which now uses an array and the index of the slider to get the relevant content.